# SQL Server views

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

How does the view actually keep its data up to date? I mean does it execute the query each time that the view is queried or used for something? Also how does this affect performance, if the view queries a SQL Server - Oracle linked server.

Comment: A view is just a stored query. It doesn't actually save this as a separate copy of data or anything. If the view pulls data from a linked server then it will execute the query remotely every single time the view is queried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple view is nothing but a stored query that is executed each time you call it. There is no performance benefit here.

You might want to have a look at stored procedures and materialized views if you need to optimize.

Comment: In SQL Server, the nomenclature is indexed views rather than materialized views.

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering. I was at work and remembered hearing that a view's data would usually be up to date and couldn't find much explanation for this.